# How can I recreate this keybinding in Spacemacs?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs, query-replace

My `.vimrc` contains this snippet:

```
nnoremap S :%s//g<LEFT><LEFT>
```

It creates a key binding which means that when I'm in normal mode, I can:

1. type the character `S`
2. type the string `find/replace`
3. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which replaces all occurrences of `find` in the current buffer with `replace`
4. return to normal mode

I'd like similar functionality in Spacemacs.  Prefixing the command with <kbd>Space</kbd> is fine.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a snippet to do it:

```
(defun my-global-ex-search ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((evil-ex-substitute-global t))
    (evil-ex "%s/")))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "S" 'my-global-ex-search)
```

The idea is to define an interactive function (can be called by the user) to call `evil-ex` with the initial input and `evil-ex-substitute` to `t`. Then we bind this function to S in the `normal state` keymap.

EDIT: added support for `/g`

Comment: Eh, typing the `/g` isn't that hard.  Thanks!

Comment: @hoosierEE in this case you can remove the let form and just put `(evil-ex "%s/")` in the function body.